# Systemjs transpile async function with typescript

Tags: typescript, async-await, systemjs, transpiler

I'm able to build `.ts` files manually with `tsc` tool. And i see wrappers generated for async/await keywords.

But I have problem to setup transpile on the fly using systemjs.

index.htm:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.16/system.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typescript/1.7.5/typescript.min.js"></script>

<script>
  System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: {
      target: 'es6'
      },
    packages: {
      '': {
        defaultJSExtensions: 'ts'
      }
    }
  });

  System.import('app').catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

app.ts:

```
console.log('hello');

async function run() {
  console.log('world');
}

run();
```

Error in Developer Console:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

See [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/S7UX29HxJNApSZbswaD7?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in specifying format 'esm'. Or add some keywords like `import` to `.ts` file so systemjs could pick correct loader.

```
System.config({
  transpiler: 'typescript',
  meta: {
    'app.ts': {
      format: 'esm'
    }
  }
});

System.import('app.ts').catch(console.error.bind(console));
```

Updated [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/S7UX29HxJNApSZbswaD7)

Now it works like a charm!